# Как правильно подключить стили для мобильной версии сайта

Tags: html, css

Есть сайт который написан для десктопов, теперь нужно сделать его респонсив для мобильных устройств, я делаю

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    * {
        display: block; /* просто проверка */
    }
}
```

Моя проблема в том, что такие стили не применяюся без `!important`, я понимаю, так происходит поскольку стили которые я пишу с медиа-запросом не "покрывают" стили десктопной версии, а отображаются вместе с ними. **Как правильно подключить `.css` для мобильной версии сайта чтобы подключались только они, а не вместе со стилями десктопа?**
Подключаю стили вот так:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

`style.css` выглядит так:

```css
 ... Код для десктопа
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    * {
        display: block; /* просто проверка */
    }
}
```

Вот весь файл стилей [`style.css`](http://d.zaix.ru/iwmd.txt). Стили на 500 строк, поэтому подумал, что файл на хостинге будет лучше

*P.S. Я пишу стили с медиа запросом в файле с десктопными стилями, понимаю что плохо, но как сделать иначе не знаю*
*P.S.S. Ответы которые я находил гуглив свой вопрос были 3-8 летней давности, я подумал что что-то да могло поменяться*

Comment: Покажите как вы подключаете стили, предоставьте код.

Comment: @MoloF я так и сделал, но без `!important` старые стили не перезаписываются

Comment: Видимо не так сделали, раз без `important` ваши старые стили не перезаписываются, ожидаю код

Comment: @MoloF Поправил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно в одном файле всё написать, и чтобы десктопные стили не применялись на мобильнике, то сделайте ограничение стилей для десктопа:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    ... тут десктопные стили
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    ... тут мобильные стили
}
```

Если же нужно только некоторые стили перебить, а не отключить десктопные совсем, то вам в любом случае придётся делать их более специфичными - добавлять вложенность в селектор или делать !important.

Если нужно не в одном файле, то подключайте стили в шапке HTML-страницы сразу с указанными условиями:

```
<link href="desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 801px)">
<link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)">
```

Comment: Не обязательно в одном файле, но мысль хорошая, проверю

Comment: В случае когда файлы разные, они оба грузятся, но стили применяются только из одного из них. Можно сделать, чтобы ненужный css не загружался?